# Generate a template inside an already created Java project

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Can I use Maven Archetype to generate say a number of custom classes depending on input from maven commands. I would like to generate a new Rest Controller, Service, Test Java classes etc depending on the class naming's given by user on the command line. Is that possible with Archetype?

All I see is examples online for brand new projects but nothing for if it's an existing project where I would like to append classes to the project.

Answer (score -1):

Bad news: no, you cannot use Maven Archetype plugin for these purposes.

Good news: you have much better alternative - write your own plugin.

In the current project we use our own maven plugins everywhere for code generation (client code .Net/JS/Java, server code, configs, etc):

- plugins are simple to implement
- plugins are extremely flexible - both in maintenance and in usage
- plugins could be integrated into maven projects and into IDE

When you add on top of this [shortening of the command line](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Shortening_the_Command_Line), then plugins usage becomes pretty marvellous:

```
> mvn codegen:rc -Dname=MyRestController
> mvn codegen:test -Dname=com.stackoverflow.answers.AboutMavenTemplatesTest
```